# PHPUnit test doubles

Tags: php, phpunit, stub

I am starting to use PHPUnit for test my code but I have some problems with understand double tests.

I try to stub a class method b to return true instead of usual behavior (false) when is called since another method

I have a code like this

```
class MyClass {
    function a()
    {
        return $this->b();
    }

    function b() 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class MyClassTest extends TestCase
{
     function testAThrowStubB()
     {
        $myClassStub = $this->getMockBuilder('\MyClass')
                              ->getMock();

        $myClassStub->expects($this->any())
                    ->method('b')
                    ->willReturn(true);

        // this assert will work
        $this->assertTrue($myClassStub->b());
        // this assert will fail
        $this->assertTrue($myClassStub->a());
     }
}
```

I thought my second assertion will work but it doesn't. I'm wrong and it is not possible? There is another way to test a function who depends on another overriding his behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you mock a class the PHPUnit framework expects that you're mocking the entire class. Any methods for which you don't specify any return values will default to returning `null` (which is why the second test was failing).

If you want to mock a subset of methods use the `setMethods` function:

```
$myClassStub = $this->getMockBuilder(MyClass::class)
    ->setMethods(["b"])
    ->getMock();

$myClassStub->expects($this->any())
            ->method('b')
            ->willReturn(true);
// this assert will work
$this->assertTrue($myClassStub->b());
// this assert will work too
$this->assertTrue($myClassStub->a());
```

This is noted in the documentation in [example 9.11](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.examples.SubjectTest.php)

Comment: Is that what it's called a "partial mock"?

Comment: @vivoconunxino yes I believe so