# Php, Dependency Injection, how to replace objects (for testing)?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

we all know the simple `DI`: reduces coupling, and enable to replace objects blahblahblah:

```
class testA
{
    public function m() {}
}

class testB
{
    public function m() {}
}

class Prj
{
    /**
     * @var testA
     */
    private $obj;

    /**
     *
     */
    public function __construct(testA $obj)
    {
         // $this->obj = new testA();
         $this->obj = $obj;
         $this->obj->m();
    }
}

$obj = new testA();
$project = new Prj($obj);
```

I understand that `$this->obj = new testA();` introduces tight coupling, if I had been done inside Prj::constructor. Thats right - and "`__construct(testA $obj)`" will not? This also hints that "`testA`" is needed.
And how to even replace it? This:

```
$obj = new testB();
$project = new Prj($obj); // FAIL!
```

just wont run, since it expects "`testA`" not "`testB`". Another, hacky way:

```
class testB extends testA
{
    public function m() {}
}
```

works until "`testA`" is not `final` or `testB` needs to `inherit` from other class... so right now that "tight coupling" doesnt seem to be eliminated for me.
And if someone says "simply remove testA hinting": what if I was developing with Java or other strong-typed language?

Comment: Sounds like in testing you want something like test doubles - [PHPUnit test doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192311/phpunit-test-doubles)

Comment: good one, but it's not the main point

Comment: Not sure entirely what you are asking - DI is more about building flexibility into a design, other features (as final) are there to help you lock down certain design decisions.  Take for example a common use of a database connection - if you hard code this connection in your class - how can you configure that connection to make this class use some specific feature (another database, transactions)?

Answer (score 3):

> Thats right - and "`__construct(testA $obj)`" will not?

No, `testA` as a type hint allows more wiggle room: it allows you to pass an instance of `testA` ***or any subclass of it***. As you have shown, you can pass `testB` as long as `testB extends testA`. That means you have *a means* of altering the behaviour.

If you want it *even more flexibly* (as you have correctly pointed out, while more flexible than `new testA` inside `__construct`, it still has *some* limitations), you can use an interface:

```
interface CanM {
    public function m();
}

class testA implements CanM {
    public function m() {}
}

...

    public function __construct(CanM $obj)
```

Now no particular class hierarchy is being imposed on you, all you need to do is pass an object that `implements CanM`, which means that it needs to have a method `m` conforming to the specified function signature.

Comment: thats actually good, I meet many "interface-like" sollution but it would then require a whole design refactoring

Comment: Well, be pragmatic about it. As long as you haven't actually `final`ized your classes and that's just a hypothetical concern, `extend`ing/mocking them for testing will do just fine. Interfaces should indeed be considered from the beginning; though it's perfectly possible to replace them little by little as necessary after the fact too.