# How to test Test Multiple classes objects Doubles in Unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

What i need

- Need to access other classes function from base class.

Problem

- cannot access $this->service->getDataAll another class service function.
- Error: Call to a member function getDataAll() on null

Class A

function Abc(){
$records = $this->getData($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
}

function getData($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)
{
$this->service->getDataAll($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
}

> Unit testing code

```
     $services = $this->getMockBuilder(ClassA::class)
        //->setMethods(array('Abc'))            
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    
   
    
    $data = array('name' =>'name');
    $indexVal = '';
    $returnVal = UnitTesting::callMethod(
        $services,
        'Abc',
        array($data)
    );
     private static function callMethod($obj, $name, array $args)
    {
                
                $class = new \ReflectionClass($obj);
                $method = $class->getMethod($name);
                $method->setAccessible(true);
                return $method->invokeArgs($obj, $args);
    }
```

So by accessing function Abc  unit testing  halts in function getData  which was accessing
service func getDataAll.

Accessing service getDataAll works

```
    $stub = $this->getMockBuilder(\App\Service::class)
                 ->setMethods(array('getDataAll'))
                 ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                 ->disableOriginalClone()
                 ->disableArgumentCloning()
                 ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
                 ->getMock();

    // Configure the stub.
    $stub->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getDataAll')
        ->willReturn(true);

    $this->assertTrue($stub->getDataAll($arg1, $arg2, $arg3));
```

- I need to access service class from Class A.
- service function must return some data.
- any solution is most welcome.

Reference

https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/test-doubles.html

[PHPUnit test doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192311/phpunit-test-doubles)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are testing? Your example starts with `Class A` and in the next code Block you are calling a method on a mocked `\App\Services`.

Comment: Thanks  sorry it was  typo updated code ,..i need to access service function  from class A

Comment: I have used disableOriginalConstructor because class a  is abstract class i think that's why cannot access service function from Unit testing code